# How to customise css for imported npm module (ie. jsoneditor)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsoneditor

This is probably general question for customising all modules imported over `npm`, but I would like to concentrate on `jsoneditor`.

I'm using react with embedded `jsoneditor`:

```
package.json
.....
"jsoneditor": "latest",
"jsoneditor-react": "latest"
```

And here is my `js` file:

```
 <JsonEditor value={this.props.root} mode="view"/>
```

Now in order to customise css I've defined following overwrites:

```
.jsoneditor-frame {
  background: $input-bg !important;
}

.jsoneditor-menu {
  background-color: $dialog-color !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid $navbar-border-color !important;
}
```

Obviously this is not the right way to to.

`npm import` installed also `sass` files for `jsoneditor` I can import them and webpack would compile it:

@import "~jsoneditor/src/scss/jsoneditor.scss";

But it has no effect....

I'm new to this whole JavaScprit world. Could someone point me to right direction about proper way of customising css that comes with jsoneditor?

Answer (score 0):

The quick-and-dirty way: npm packages, if they come with something like .sass or .less, very often also come with the compiled .css files. You can find those somewhere in the package's folder in node_modules. You could potentially modify something there directly.

The also-quick-and-dirty-but-not-as-dirty-way: Inspecting your imported elements in the browser can also lead you to the correct css id/className, which you can then overwrite.

Comment: in my case npm package of jsoneditor comes with sass, but importing it into my project has no effects, it still references provides css file.....

Comment: are you using webpack? you might need a load for that particuar kind of stylesheet